# Get a value from Array output

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber

Using the below property I'm able to get Subscriber Properties.

```
var results = Subscriber.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:Sk});
```

The results output is an array.  How do I get particular value from it?  Example: the results output is something like below

```
"results":[,
"EmailAddress":"xxxx@facebook.com",
"SubscriberKey":"xxx@facebook.com",
"ID":80503436,
"EmailTypePreference":"HTML",
"Status":"Unsubscribed"
```

How to get Status from this output.

I tried this and many others but doesn't work.

```
var currentStatus = results[].status;
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the number in the brackets? eg `results[0].Status`?  I also want to note that this is case sensitive, so `status` won't work, but `Status` should.

Comment: Can you share with us more accurate output of `console.log(results);`, please?

Comment: @Gortonington that worked! I did try results[0] too earlier, but lost me on the case-sensitive.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the case-sensitiveness put a block on my attempts.

`results[0].Status` (with the S capitalized on Status) gave the expected result.  Thanks for the comments that pointed out the issue.